# g++ error: invalid preprocessing directive #INCLUDE

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, g++

I tried testing MinGW under Windows 7 with a simple Hello World program and got the following errors:

```
C:\code\helloworld.cpp:2:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #INCLUDE
C:\code\helloworld.cpp:3:7: error: expected neested-name-specifier before 'namespace'
C:\code\helloworld.cpp:3:17: error: expected ';' before 'std'
C:\code\helloworld.cpp:3:17: error: 'std' does not name a type
C:\code\helloworld.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\code\helloworld.cpp:7:2: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
```

My original code was as follows:

```
//Hello, World
#INCLUDE <iostream>
using namesapce std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need lower case `#include`

Comment: and there's a typo: namesapce -> namespace

Comment: Wow, I feel so noobish right now!

Answer (score 6):

`#include` should be lower case. C++ is case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

It should be lowercase. Use `#include`.

Also, it's `using namespace std;` (typo in `namespace`).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, world!";
   return 0;
}
```